# Check if I'm in a shell through ranger

Tags: ranger

In ranger, you can hit `S` to jump into a shell and `ctrl+D` to get back to ranger.

When I've been in a shell for a while and I want to jump to ranger, I'm unsure if this is a regular shell and I should hit `ranger` or if I'm in the shell through ranger already and I should hit `ctrl+D`.

If I hit `ctrl+D` wrongly, my terminal will close. If I use `ranger` wrongly, I'll get a nested instance of ranger within ranger.

Is there a way to check if I'm already in a ranger shell?

If there is a command, I could alias it to something like `rangerp` which will output "True" if I am in a shell and "False" if I'm not.

Comment: your workflow may be easier if you use ranger-cd to change the directory and then exit into the shell instead of shelling out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the parent pid helps regarding this.

```
[root@centos8 ranger-1.9.3]# ps -fp $PPID
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      3240  3214  0 08:03 pts/1    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 -O /usr/local/bin/ranger
[root@centos8 ranger-1.9.3]#
```

So try

```
ps -fp $PPID | grep -q ranger && echo True || echo False
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I think this should work. I'll port it to my shell (fish) and then accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever Ranger spawns a shell, it increments the environment variable `RANGER_LEVEL`:

```
$ echo $RANGER_LEVEL

$ ranger             # Open Ranger and enter a nested shell
$ echo $RANGER_LEVEL                           
1
$ ranger             # Do the same thing from the nested shell
$ echo $RANGER_LEVEL                            
2
```

For the command you requested, you can do something like:

```
alias inranger="[ $RANGER_LEVEL ] && echo True || echo False"
```

If you don't want to waste time running the command or want to make sure you don't forget to run it, you can add the desired information to your prompt by editing your shell's RC file:

```
if [ -n "$RANGER_LEVEL" ]; then 
    export PS1="[r$RANGER_LEVEL]$PS1";
fi
```

And there you go:

```
$ ranger     # Open Ranger and drop into a shell
[r1]$ ranger # One more time
[r2]$        # ...
```

Source: https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/1374

Answer (score 0):

##### Fix using fish shell

Create the file *~/.config/fish/functions/ranger.fish* with the following content:

```
function ranger --description 'Simple, vim-like file manager'
    if test -n "$RANGER_LEVEL"
        exit
    else
        command ranger $argv
    end
end
```